# Dropping rows in a dataframe based on a specified string in a specific column

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some data here and I'm trying to drop the rows that contain the aborted string in the job status column, however I'm getting an error

> TypeError: data type 'aborted' not understood.

[image]

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Test.csv')

    def drop_aborts():
            remove_aborts = df.select_dtypes(exclude='aborted')
            df.drop(remove_aborts, axis=0, inplace=True)
            logging.info('Test drop aborts')
```

Im trying this solution but im still getting aborted?

```
gas_data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Userstest.csv')
logging.info('Loaded CSV into Dataframe')


def drop_aborts():
    new = gas_data.loc[~gas_data['Job status'].str.contains('aborted')]
    print(new)
```

```
gas_data.to_dict():


{'Old Serial No': {0: 'L0856083739M', 1: 'L1351868931M', 2: '0216487S', 3: 'U6S00830291302', 4: '845413', 5: '223771', 6: 'G4A02952840801', 7: '5005630', 8: 'L1256021461M', 9: 'L1256355150M', 10: 'G4A00643541101', 11: '80108', 12: 'G4A60543411702', 13: 'G4A02624811001', 14: 'E6S05083711556', 15: 'L1256089889M', 16: 'E6S02625591556', 17: '238096', 18: '540452', 19: '210466', 20: 'G4K67349440711', 21: 'E6S12032281860', 22: 'G4A01271950201', 23: 'G4A01814800501', 24: '5039247', 25: 'L1451915026M', 26: 'G4K03341860101'}, 'Appointment Date': {0: '########', 1: nan, 2: '########', 3: '########', 4: '########', 5: '########', 6: '########', 7: '########', 8: '########', 9: '########', 10: '########', 11: '########', 12: '########', 13: '########', 14: '########', 15: '########', 16: '########', 17: '########', 18: '########', 19: '########', 20: '########', 21: '########', 22: '########', 23: '########', 24: '########', 25: '########', 26: '########'}, 'Appointment Time': {0: 'AM', 1: 'PM', 2: 'AM', 3: 'AM', 4: 'AM', 5: 'PM', 6: 'AM', 7: 'AM', 8: 'AM', 9: 'AM', 10: 'AM', 11: 'AM', 12: 'AM', 13: 'AM', 14: 'AM', 15: 'PM', 16: 'AM', 17: 'AM', 18: 'PM', 19: 'AM', 20: 'AM', 21: 'PM', 22: 'AM', 23: 'AM', 24: 'AM', 25: 'PM', 26: 'AM'}, 'Cancellation Date': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan, 8: nan, 9: nan, 10: nan, 11: nan, 12: nan, 13: nan, 14: nan, 15: nan, 16: nan, 17: nan, 18: nan, 19: nan, 20: nan, 21: nan, 22: nan, 23: nan, 24: nan, 25: nan, 26: nan}, 'Cancellation Time': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan, 8: nan, 9: nan, 10: nan, 11: nan, 12: nan, 13: nan, 14: nan, 15: nan, 16: nan, 17: nan, 18: nan, 19: nan, 20: nan, 21: nan, 22: nan, 23: nan, 24: nan, 25: nan, 26: nan}, 'Job status': {0: 'aborted', 1: 'aborted', 2: 'completed', 3: 'aborted', 4: 'completed', 5: 'completed', 6: 'aborted', 7: 'completed', 8: 'aborted', 9: 'completed', 10: 'completed', 11: 'aborted', 12: 'aborted', 13: 'completed', 14: 'completed', 15: 'completed', 16: 'completed', 17: 'completed', 18: 'aborted', 19: 'completed', 20: 'aborted', 21: 'completed', 22: 'completed', 23: 'completed', 24: 'completed', 25: 'completed', 26: 'completed'}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can negate (`~`) `str.contains()` and return back a new filtered DataFrame without the rows that contains 'aborted'.

Using @Karina's sample DF:

```
a = ['30/07/2021', '30/07/2021', '30/07/2021', '30/07/2021', '30/07/2021']
b = ['aborted', 'aborted' , 'completed', 'aborted', 'completed']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Appointment date': a, 'Job status': b})
```

---

You can use:

```
new = df.loc[~df['Job status'].str.contains('aborted')]
```

Which will give back:

```
  Appointment date Job status
2       30/07/2021  completed
4       30/07/2021  completed
```

Note that you can use `or` in `str.contains` and also make it case-insensitive:

```
new = df.loc[~df['Job status'].str.contains(r'aborted|abort',case=False)]
```

**Update**:

```
from numpy import nan
gas_data = pd.DataFrame({'Old Serial No': {0: 'L0856083739M', 1: 'L1351868931M', 2: '0216487S', 3: 'U6S00830291302', 4: '845413', 5: '223771', 6: 'G4A02952840801', 7: '5005630', 8: 'L1256021461M', 9: 'L1256355150M', 10: 'G4A00643541101', 11: '80108', 12: 'G4A60543411702', 13: 'G4A02624811001', 14: 'E6S05083711556', 15: 'L1256089889M', 16: 'E6S02625591556', 17: '238096', 18: '540452', 19: '210466', 20: 'G4K67349440711', 21: 'E6S12032281860', 22: 'G4A01271950201', 23: 'G4A01814800501', 24: '5039247', 25: 'L1451915026M', 26: 'G4K03341860101'}, 'Appointment Date': {0: '########', 1: nan, 2: '########', 3: '########', 4: '########', 5: '########', 6: '########', 7: '########', 8: '########', 9: '########', 10: '########', 11: '########', 12: '########', 13: '########', 14: '########', 15: '########', 16: '########', 17: '########', 18: '########', 19: '########', 20: '########', 21: '########', 22: '########', 23: '########', 24: '########', 25: '########', 26: '########'}, 'Appointment Time': {0: 'AM', 1: 'PM', 2: 'AM', 3: 'AM', 4: 'AM', 5: 'PM', 6: 'AM', 7: 'AM', 8: 'AM', 9: 'AM', 10: 'AM', 11: 'AM', 12: 'AM', 13: 'AM', 14: 'AM', 15: 'PM', 16: 'AM', 17: 'AM', 18: 'PM', 19: 'AM', 20: 'AM', 21: 'PM', 22: 'AM', 23: 'AM', 24: 'AM', 25: 'PM', 26: 'AM'}, 'Cancellation Date': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan, 8: nan, 9: nan, 10: nan, 11: nan, 12: nan, 13: nan, 14: nan, 15: nan, 16: nan, 17: nan, 18: nan, 19: nan, 20: nan, 21: nan, 22: nan, 23: nan, 24: nan, 25: nan, 26: nan}, 'Cancellation Time': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: nan, 5: nan, 6: nan, 7: nan, 8: nan, 9: nan, 10: nan, 11: nan, 12: nan, 13: nan, 14: nan, 15: nan, 16: nan, 17: nan, 18: nan, 19: nan, 20: nan, 21: nan, 22: nan, 23: nan, 24: nan, 25: nan, 26: nan}, 'Job status': {0: 'aborted', 1: 'aborted', 2: 'completed', 3: 'aborted', 4: 'completed', 5: 'completed', 6: 'aborted', 7: 'completed', 8: 'aborted', 9: 'completed', 10: 'completed', 11: 'aborted', 12: 'aborted', 13: 'completed', 14: 'completed', 15: 'completed', 16: 'completed', 17: 'completed', 18: 'aborted', 19: 'completed', 20: 'aborted', 21: 'completed', 22: 'completed', 23: 'completed', 24: 'completed', 25: 'completed', 26: 'completed'}})

new = gas_data.loc[~gas_data['Job status'].str.contains('aborted')]
```

`new` Will print back:

```
Out[841]: 
     Old Serial No Appointment Date  ... Cancellation Time  Job status
2         0216487S         ########  ...               NaN   completed
4           845413         ########  ...               NaN   completed
5           223771         ########  ...               NaN   completed
7          5005630         ########  ...               NaN   completed
9     L1256355150M         ########  ...               NaN   completed
10  G4A00643541101         ########  ...               NaN   completed
13  G4A02624811001         ########  ...               NaN   completed
14  E6S05083711556         ########  ...               NaN   completed
15    L1256089889M         ########  ...               NaN   completed
16  E6S02625591556         ########  ...               NaN   completed
17          238096         ########  ...               NaN   completed
19          210466         ########  ...               NaN   completed
21  E6S12032281860         ########  ...               NaN   completed
22  G4A01271950201         ########  ...               NaN   completed
23  G4A01814800501         ########  ...               NaN   completed
24         5039247         ########  ...               NaN   completed
25    L1451915026M         ########  ...               NaN   completed
26  G4K03341860101         ########  ...               NaN   completed

[18 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: I'm still getting aborted? :( I'm not sure where I'm going wrong! I have edited what i 'm using above.

Comment: Can you post your data as text, using ```df.to_dict()```, and posting that so I can replicate exactly please? Don't worry we will solve the issue

Comment: Posted as text!

Comment: Thanks for posting it. Try my code now below 'Update'. I have included the gas_data (which is derived from what you posted), the code to remove 'aborted' and the new dataset that only contains 'completed' in Job status.

Answer (score 0):

I made up some data since you didn't provide sample data:

```
a = np.arange(7)
b = ['a', 'b' , 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a']
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': a, 'y': b})
print(df)
newdf = df.drop(df[~(df['y'] != 'a')].index)
print(newdf)
```

Output:

```
   x  y
0  0  a
1  1  b
2  2  a
3  3  a
4  4  b
5  5  b
6  6  a
   x  y
1  1  b
4  4  b
5  5  b
```

In this case I removed the row where `y == 'a'`. I think you will be able to apply this to your code.

---edit---

```
a = ['30/07/2021', '30/07/2021', '30/07/2021', '30/07/2021', '30/07/2021']
b = ['aborted', 'aborted' , 'completed', 'aborted', 'completed']

df = pd.DataFrame({'Appointment date': a, 'Job status': b})
print(df)
newdf = df.drop(df[~(df['Job status'] != 'aborted')].index)
print(newdf)
```

Output:

```
  Appointment date Job status
0       30/07/2021    aborted
1       30/07/2021    aborted
2       30/07/2021  completed
3       30/07/2021    aborted
4       30/07/2021  completed
  Appointment date Job status
2       30/07/2021  completed
4       30/07/2021  completed
```

Comment: Im not following this, how would i apply this to my x and y axis? 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Wbj-XU0vxcL6sjI7X77w4krALmGP91xD1P1Tt6NGyd8/edit#gid=0

Comment: I'm not sure this would work as the data will be coming in at different dates, and it wont always be 5 at a time to assign to a and b. Also the date really doesn't matter, the main issues is if there is an 'aborted' in the 'Job status' collom, The entire row needs to be removed.

Comment: I just add the date there since you sent me a link to your data. I am aware that the date is completely irrelevant, that's why I event wrote ``np.arange`` (since it doesn't matter anyway). And the fact that it won't always be 5 also not important. Never have I put in my code the hard number ``5``. the code will work regardless the length of the data. I don't get what is your actual problem.

Comment: Im using your code, but the aborted are not being removed, and im not sure what im doing wrong? The code runs and prints but the aborted rows dont get deleted?